# Google app script - Getting last sheet row updated

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have a script associated with a google sheet that it's call after a Google form is submitted.

Actually I can get all rows or the last but in case one form answer is updated I need to find this row updated to make my treatment.

Is there a way to do that?

This is my two case:

```
// Getting last row data
function getSpreadSheetLastRowData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();
  return sheet.getRange('A'+row+':BG'+row).getValues();
}

// Getting all rows data
function getSpreadSheetAllData() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var row = sheet.getLastRow();
  return sheet.getRange('A2:BG'+row).getValues();
}
```

Comment: Hello Jérémy, do you want to get the last updated row automatically and right after the form submission?

Comment: On google form submit, it triggered a google app script and i want to get the updated row (in case of edited one answer) or the lastest row (in case of new answer).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write an event handler for the onFormSubmit event object and attach it to your spreadsheet.

From the Spreadsheet linked to your Form go to `Tools > Script Editor`.
Here write a function to install the trigger:

```
function installTriggerToSpreadsheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sumbissionHandler')
  .forSpreadsheet(ss)
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();
}
```

Now your trigger will handle the form submission calling the `submissionHandler` function inside the Spreadsheet context.
This means you can read the affected row by using a function like this:

```
function submissionHandler(e) {
 var affectedRow = e.range.getRow();

 // ... Apply your treatment.
}
```

### References:

[Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

[Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Sad i can only upvote once; you just saved me a ton of documentation scouring. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a script that is triggered by a form submission then take the event object lets call it e.  Then e.range is the range that was edited in the linked sheet. So `e.range.getRow()` is the row and `e.range.getSheet().getName()` is the name of the linked sheet.

[form submit object for spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)

Comment: Do you have an exemple of using the e with script?
I didn't find where i initialize/get the e argument.